# Custom extension download problem

Tags: .net, web-applications

In my web application, I am generating a document with a custom extension and providing the user with the link to download. The download fails with custom extension but goes fine with predefined extensions like "xml". I have no idea what is going wrong!

Is this some kind of access rights problem? I am running it under Windows 2003 server!

Any help will be highly appreciated!

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the mime-types supported of your server configuration, and add yours extensions to the list.